# How to use a Powershell output into an Ansible Playbook

Tags: powershell, azure, ansible

I have a simple Powershell script that checks if two things and writes results into an output. My idea is to use that output in an Ansible Playbook as a variable that will be used to reboot a machine, or not (however in the example below I have a PING test command).

My PS1

```
#Change computer description
$CDesc = Get-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\"
If($CDesc.GetValue("srvcomment") -eq $null) {
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\" -Name "srvcomment" -Value "PROD | AZI | V | APPLICA | SQL" -PropertyType String
} else {
    $step1 = Write-Output "Step1"
}

#Check if CD drive is available
$CDletter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive | select -ExpandProperty Drive
If($CDletter -eq $null) {
    $step2 = Write-Output "Step2"
}



if (($step1) -and ($step2)) {Write-Host "already_updated"}
```

My Playbook:

```
# Run post build scripts on machines taggedd with AnsibleVM1 from commad line variable with "{{ hosts }}"
# ansible-playbook test.yml -i azure_rm.py --extra-vars "hosts=displayName_AnsibleVM1" --ask-vault-pass -vvvv

- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
   - ./vars/vault.yml
   - ./vars/vars.yml

  tasks:
   - include_vars: vault.yml
   - name: test script
     script: ./files/test.ps1
     register: result

   - set_fact: machineId={{result.stdout_lines.0}}

   - win_ping:
       when: machineId.already_ASDF
```

However, the PING (or soon-to-be REBOOT) module still runs. Here is my output:

```
TASK [test script] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/beefcake/cloudy/Ansible/test.yml:13
<51.x.x.x> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: admin on PORT 5986 TO 51.x.x.x
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
<51.x.x.x> PUT "/home/beefcake/cloudy/Ansible/files/test.ps1" TO "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1508512681.4-33957924788761\test.ps1"
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [AnsibleVM1] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "failed": false, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stdout": "already_updated\n", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "already_updated"
    ]
}
Read vars_file './vars/vault.yml'
Read vars_file './vars/vars.yml'

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/beefcake/cloudy/Ansible/test.yml:17
ok: [AnsibleVM1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "machineId": "already_updated"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false
}
Read vars_file './vars/vault.yml'
Read vars_file './vars/vars.yml'

TASK [win_ping] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/beefcake/cloudy/Ansible/test.yml:19
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
<51.x.x.x> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: admin on PORT 5986 TO 51.x.x.x
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
ok: [AnsibleVM1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
AnsibleVM1                 : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match string (eg. check if the output value of the script is "already updated") you would to that as such:

`- win_ping:
       when: machineId == 'already_updated'`

machineId doesn't have an attribute, it's a simple string value.

In order to save a step, you could also do:

   `- win_ping:
       when: result.stdout_lines[0] == 'already_updated'`

In order to build more complicated Powershell logic and still interact with Ansible you essentially have two options:

1. Have your Powershell script output json (using the "Convertto-json" cmdlet in conjunction with Write-Output) and use Ansible's builtin json parser to parse it
2. Write an Ansible module in Powershell.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, however the first 2 `when` options you mentioned have not helped, it still pings. Just for daigs, I changed `result.stdout_lines[0]` to `[1]` to see if it would fail, but it didn't, just ran straight through. I had also tried `ConvertTo-JSON` for `if (($step1) -and ($step2)) {Write-Host "already_updated"}`  Powershell, but oddly enough it outputs exactly the same as what you see here if I don't, and it hasn't made a difference either. One last thing, I had changed `{Write-Host` to `{Write-Output` which I _think_ makes it into a variable, but it has made no diff :(

Comment: that's weird. Can you use the "debug" module to print the value of "machineId" after you've set it?

Comment: Also, I gues it's expected that it runs the win_ping module? If the Powershell script outputs "already_updated" then the win_ping module is run. At least that's the logic in my examples in the above answer.